# Magento 1.7 to Magento 2.1 Database

Tags: database, magento2-migration-tool, magento-2.1

We are discussing the idea of upgrading from 1.7 to Magento 2.1.

**Our current system is** 
PHP Version
5.3.26
MySQL Version
5.5.31-30.3-log

My preferred method would be to create a sub folder with Magento 2.1 installed and take my time to move stuff over.  I like doing it this way because I may have others working on it as well.  
**Will there be an issue with upgraded PHP and MySQL for Magento 1.7?**

Answer (score 0):

My experience with the migration process:

As an intern on the team, we duplicated our Magento system and used that sandbox to tinker with the migration process from ver 1.9 to ver 2.0.

We used [UB Data Migration](https://github.com/ubertheme/magento2_data_migration%22UB%20Data%20Migration%22) to map the database of products/customers but I believe there is a bug in Step 7 of the process which means Reviews & Rating Data won't be imported so that part was done manually.

Comment: Where did you create the sandbox?

Comment: We use DigitalOcean to host the websites.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, we decided to set up a new hosting account for the purpose of creating a Magento 2.1 environment.  This will help us with not having to worry about the effects of an upgraded PHP or mySQL on the current live site.  We wanted a hosting environment because we have more then one person building the site. Not the cleanest way to approach this, but it works for us.